# How to define and use a simple resource in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am NEW to WPF.  I have the following XAML code:

```
</Window>
        ...
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300">WORD1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="300">WORD2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="300">WORD3</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I would like to define "300" as a resource (say "myTop") and replace all Canvas.Top="300" with Canvas.Top="myTop".

How can I do this in WPF/XAML?  I looked into StaticResources and DataTemplates, but could not figure out a simple way.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also use a [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to add xmlns to the window

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And then define resource like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="theTop">300</System:Double>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then you can use it:

```
<Canvas>
  <TextBlock Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="{StaticResource theTop}">WORD1</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.  Could not find an answer in any of the several WPF books I have, was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

This one's a little trickier than you'd first think, because you essentially want to define a "constant" of type `System.Double` to reference later on.

To get to that type you'll need to use the `System` namespace from mscorlib.dll in your XAML, so add this line to the top of your file under the other namespace declarations:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Now we can use that XML namespace to define our resource:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <s:Double x:Key="foo">300</s:Double>
    </Canvas.Resources>
```

... and refer to it from the TextBlocks:

```
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="{StaticResource foo}">WORD1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="{StaticResource foo}">WORD2</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="{StaticResource foo}">WORD3</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  I marked the other reply as the answer because it was essentially the same but earlier than yours by a minute, although yours also has the "s" abbreviation for System.  You should consider writing a book on WPF as you have a knack for explaining things.  Thanks again.

Comment: Both answers (yours and from JleruOHeP) work, and it was great because when I change the resource definition in the Visual Studio XAML editor, all words are aligned at once!  Excellent. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 8.1, the type has to be a basic type of the XAML language, and can be accessed like this:

```
...
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
...

<Page.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="theTop">300</System:Double>
</Page.Resources>
```

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771178.aspx